# How to call a user command multiple times

Tags: vim

I want to call a user defined command multiple times. Here is a command definition:

```
command! -count=2 Delete d
```

I call the command in the command line with:

```
:2 Delete
```

But this call deletes only one line. So the command is called only once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The count isn't automatically passed to your custom command; you need to specify where you want Vim to insert it via the special `<count>` keyword, e.g.:

```
command! -count=2 Delete <count>d
```

See `:help <count>`.